# How to get files list with checksums

Tags: unix, rsync

I have to servers (suppose master and slave), slave is synced with master by rsync.
I need to get list of files on master and their checksums. Only all the files and their checksums.
Is it possible with rsync without putting scripts on master server or browsing with scp/ssh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I've found the answers.
Rsync can output checksum for files by adding: --out-format="%C", but this works only on unstable 3.1, that is why it's not widespread.
So i decided to go with just comparing files by checksums ( -c option ) with --dry-run options to just compare locations and dump each file status.

Comment: Did you get this from the source code?  I don't see `%C` documented in `man rsync`.

Comment: Ah, it's in `man rsyncd.conf`: %C the full-file MD5 checksum if --checksum is enabled or a file was transferred (only for protocol 30 or above).